# the math model of the slot machines

Tags: probability, statistics

Could you please tell me or give me the sources - what we understand by a math model of the slot machine.
What does it mean that the game is well or badly designed?

Comment: Where did you see these terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, the mathematical model consists of winning combination probabilities and the pay table.

Firstly, for any casino the game will be badly designed if the expected value of a single game is greater or equal to the bet. The house always has to win given enough time.

Secondly, the mathematical model is considered badly designed if nobody wants to play the game or play long enough for "given enough time" to kick in. However, that has more to do with psychology and gambling strategies. If the most common strategy is a combination of "only play on this machine if the balance is positive after the first 4 games" and "never play this model of machines again if 4 times in a row the balance was negative after 4 games" the model has to reflect that to retain players with high probability. This entry is a good read about some of the aspects https://www.casinoinside.ro/mathematical-models-of-slot-games/?lang=en